# sqlite c++ and unsigned int key

Tags: c++, sqlite

I am trying to migrate to SQLite. In my C++ program I use `unsigned int key` to store id's. When I serialize data from C++ program to SQLite and then unserialize it back or browse the database, I see negative values (signed) in the column.

I bind `unsigned ints` on serialization with this function:

```
sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, 1, key);
```

Table column for keys is declared as `INT` while creation. Maybe here is my mistake?

Any suggestion how to correctly serialize `unsigned ints` into SQLite and load it back without changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite's type system doesn't support unsigned integers.  But you can use `sqlite3_bind_int64` instead: `unsigned int` (assuming it's 32-bit) can be losslessly converted to `int64_t`.

Comment: already trying and receive error "19" from SQLite... maybe need some special convert to post `unsigned int` to `sqlite3_bind_int64` ? thanks

Comment: Error 19 is [`SQLITE_CONSTRAINT`](https://sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html). It is described as *"Abort due to constraint violation"*. I had the same issue and switching to `sqlite3_bind_int64` resolved it. However, my columns were type `INTEGER`, not `INT`. Maybe you need to delete the database and then re-create it using `INTEGER` for the column.