# sqlite c++ and unsigned integer manipulation

Tags: c++, sqlite

Question related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17305811/sqlite-c-and-unsigned-int-key). Okay, now I am bind my `unsigned integer` with `bind_text` function. After this at the `INTEGER` column I see correctly stored `unsigned integer` value. Now, I want to receive it from base to c++ variable `unsigned int xxx`. What is the best way to do so? Request as the text and then convert to `ui`? Or request as `sqlite_int64` then somehow convert to `unsigned int` ? Please, add some example code. thanks.

Comment: Why are you binding with `sqlite3_bind_text()` instead of `sqlite3_bind_int()`?

Comment: @trojanfoe because valuer is `unsigned` and its show as negative if bind with `_int()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is exactly one correct way to bind an `unsigned integer`: use [sqlite3_bind_int64](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html):

```
unsigned int key = ...;

sqlite3_bind_int64(stmt, 1, key);
```

To get such a value back from a query, use [sqlite3_column_64](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html):

```
key = (unsigned int)sqlite3_column_int64(query_stmt, 0);
```

Comment: I assume `sqlite3_bind_int()` would work just as well, except that numbers > 0x80000000 would appear negative in the database, but would translate back fine using `sqlite3_column_int()`?

Comment: It would not work, because *any* other method of accessing these values would not result in the same values.

Comment: Only for values that (mis) use the sign-bit, so most values would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

It's late answer for this question. I'd help somebody who deal with this problem. The solution could be very easy way that you could use UNSIGNED BIGINT or UNSIGNED INT data type for table then insert the data as signed value(eg. uint64_t v = xxx; insert (int64_t)v). After that you could convert the data type when it back with splite3_column_int64 function.(eg. uint64_t rv = (uint64_t)splite3_column_int64(stmt, 0);)
파이팅~!